# Not able to add more property in Json file VS Code

Tags: json, typescript, automation, automated-tests, playwright

I'm not able to add and call more properties in my JSON file. 
Basically, I can add a new property in JSON, but when I call this property I get an error message:  "Property does not exist on type ‘{}’ in TypeScript"

I needed to create a new file and add more properties, but after saving the new file, the issue is back.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Json File:

```
}
    "firmware": "2.0",
    "expiry": "'1year'",
    "test": "ts"
    
}
```

Code:

```
const example = new EPage(page, data.firmware, data.expiry, data.test);
```

In the code data.firmware and data.expiry works fine, but data.test throws me an error.
Property 'test' does not exist on type '{}'.

Yes, I saved the JSON file before calling it in my code.

Comment: How are you reading the json file? Can you share more code?

Comment: I'm importing it: `import * as data from "../data/jsonReader.cred.json";`
and then calling it data.test

Comment: Try to use bracket notation instead: const example = new EPage(page, data['firmware'], data['expiry'], data['test']);

Comment: I think it was a bug in my VS code. After restart the software it worked fine. Thanks for the tip :)